# Show WMS with OSM

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, wms

First, sorry for my English but is not my native tongue.
I would like to ask you if you know why my maps are not working. I have two WMS with geoserver and OSM working with OpenLayers. The three maps are showing, the problem is when OSM is "On" the other 2 are in the back and the are not showed. Here is my code.

```
function init(){ 

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            allOverlays: true,

        });
        //Geoserver WMS
        var towns = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Towns",
                "http://XXXX/geoserver/isle/wms", {layers: 'isleofwight:Towns', transparent: true}, {visibility: false},{isBaseLayer: false});
        map.addLayer(towns);

        var outline = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Outline",
            "http://XXXX/geoserver/isle/wms", {layers: 'isleofwight:Outline', transparent: true}, {visibility: false},{isBaseLayer: false});
        map.addLayer(outline);

        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");
        map.addLayer(osm);
```

Thank you very much

As I can't answer my same question, I edit to say that I found the solution, just in case someone will need it, the problem was to insert the layers one by one, you have to add all at the same time.

```
map.addLayers([osm, towns, outline]);
```

Now is working perfectly :D

Comment: Actually you can answer your own question.

Comment: I couldn't because I tried to do before 8 hours and I don't enough votes to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to nmtoken and NorthLand.

To show multiple sources at a time they have to be given to the same layer and separated by a comma (no spaces allowed or it won't work) :

```
params:{'LAYERS': 'Test:TestImagery,Test:Vector'},
```

A working example would be:

```
var sUrl = 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms';
var oParam = JSON.parse({"LAYERS": "ne:NE1_HR_LC_SR_W_DR,topp:states", "TILED": true});

var wmsLayer = new TileLayer({
    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new TileWms({
      url: sUrl,
      params: oParam,
      serverType: "geoserver",
      transition: 0
    }),
    isBaseLayer: true
  });

this.map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

This will render 2 tiled images on the same layer at the same time.